# How do I show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Let $H$ be a unique subgroup of $G$ of index $k$. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

My attempt: Since, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$; and assume that $|H|=m$,

Now define a mapping $\phi: H \rightarrow gHg^{-1}$ by $\phi(h)=ghg^{-1}$, for some $h \in H$, and $g\in G$.

**Well defined**:

Let $h_1,h_2 \in H$, and $h_1=h_2$ then, $gh_1g^{-1}=gh_2g^{-1}$. This implies $\phi(h_1)=\phi(h_2)$.

**Homomorphism**:

Let $h_1,h_2 \in H$, then
$$\phi(h_1h_2)=g(h_1h_2)g^{-1}=gh_1g^{-1}gh_2g^{-1}=\phi(h_1)\phi(h_2)$$

**One-to-One**:

Let $\phi(h_1)=\phi(h_2)$ then
$$gh_1g^{-1}=gh_2g^{-1}\implies h_1=h_2$$

**Onto**:

Let $ghg^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$, then there is $h \in H$, such that $\phi(h)=ghg^{-1}$.

This implies $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ are isomorphic to each other. So $|gHg^{-1}|=m$; By the uniqueness of the subgroup, so $H=gHg^{-1}$. This implies $Hg=gH$. Hence, H is a normal subgroup of G.

Is this proof correct for this question?
I am confused how do I use index $k$ property.

Anyone can suggest me some improvements or directions?

Comment: your proof that it is a group homomorphism is wrong. You only have one operation in a group which you have denoted multiplicatively

Comment: Fortunately it is easily fixed. We have $gh_1h_2g^{-1} = gh_1 (g^{-1} g) h_2 g^{-1} = (gh_1g^{-1})(gh_2g^{-1})$

Comment: @Mummy_the_turkey Thanks. Is this idea correct to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes it should work. If you are being very careful you should also check that $gHg^{-1}$ is also a subgroup. You ask "how to use the index $k$ property" - you did, that is how you concluded that  $gHg^{-1} = H$.

Answer (score 1):

For any finite group $G$, element $g \in G$, and subgroup

$H \subseteq G, \tag 1$

the mapping

$H \to G, \; H \ni h \mapsto ghg^{-1} \in gHg^{-1} \tag 2$

is an isomorphism 'twixt $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$, for this map is clearly injective, since if

$gh_1g^{-1} = gh_2g^{-1}, \tag 3$

then

$h_1g^{-1} = eh_1g^{-1} = g^{-1}gh_1g^{-1} = g^{-1}gh_2g^{-1} = eh_2g^{-1} = h_2g^{-1}, \tag 4$

whence

$h_1 = h_1 e = h_1g^{-1}g = h_2g^{-1}g = h_2e = h_2; \tag 5$

here $e \in G$ is the identity element; furthermore, the map (2) is manifestly surjective by definition; therefore

$\vert H \vert = \vert gHg^{-1} \vert, \tag 6$

that is, the two subgroups $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ are of the same cardinaliity.  By Lagrange's theorem,

$[G:H] = \vert G \vert / \vert H \vert = \vert G \vert / \vert gHg^{-1} \vert = [G:gHg^{-1}], \tag 7$

that is, $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ are of the same index.  Thus

$H = gHg^{-1}; \tag 8$

since this holds for any $g \in G$,

$H \lhd G, \tag 9$

$OE\Delta$.